# Correct way to allocate memory to std::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management, shared-ptr

I have implemented a function where the identity is given to me and out of my control. It returns `std::shared_ptr<const void>`. In the function i allocate an arbitrary amount of memory, and return access to it though the shared_ptr.

My memory allocation is done with `new unsigned char[123]`. The problem is that valgrind detects a mismatch between the usage of new and delete variants. While i use `new[](unsigned)` to allocate memory, the shared_ptr destructor uses `delete(void*)` to deallocate it, and valgrind warns whenever you are using the "incorrect" deallocator for an allocation.

In more practical terms, i wrote this test case to show what i mean:

```
TEST(Example, Test1)
{
  unsigned char* mem = new unsigned char[123];
  std::shared_ptr<const void> ptr(mem);
}
```

The valgrind report says

```
==45794== Mismatched free() / delete / delete []
==45794==    at 0x4C2A64B: operator delete(void*) (vg_replace_malloc.c:576)
==45794==    by 0x40B7B5: _M_release (shared_ptr_base.h:150)
==45794==    by 0x40B7B5: ~__shared_count (shared_ptr_base.h:659)
==45794==    by 0x40B7B5: ~__shared_ptr (shared_ptr_base.h:925)
==45794==    by 0x40B7B5: ~shared_ptr (shared_ptr.h:93)
==45794==    by 0x40B7B5: Example_Test1_Test::TestBody() (test.cc:108)
==45794==  Address 0x5cb6290 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 123 alloc'd
==45794==    at 0x4C29CAF: operator new[](unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:423)
==45794==    by 0x40B72E: Example_Test1_Test::TestBody() (test.cc:107)
```

I want to avoid valgrind filters if possible.

What is the correct way to allocate an arbitrary amount of data and return as a `std::shared_ptr<const void>`?

Comment: What about allocation with malloc?

Comment: If you use `malloc` instead, you get a similar warning because you have not matching `free`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you give `shared_ptr<T>` a `T` pointer, it assumes that you created a single object and implies the deleter `delete p;`. If your allocation was actually performed with array-new, you need to pass an appropriate deleter that performs `delete[] p;`. You can reuse `std::default_delete` if you like:

```
return static_pointer_cast<const void>(
    std::shared_ptr<unsigned char>(
        new unsigned char[N],
        std::default_delete<unsigned char[]>()));
```

(You don't even need the outer cast, since the conversion is implied.)

In C++17, `shared_ptr` supports arrays, so you can say

```
shared_ptr<unsigned char[]>(new unsigned char[N])
```

there and get the correct deleter (and then convert to void).

Comment: [Demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/24Or4rgU851gtSYx), [modified demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/tzFXH0NyKUPTht5E).