# Using shared_ptr with CArray?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, smart-pointers

In my application, I need to use CArray to manage an arry of pointers. Each pointer points to an object allocated in heap.

Since CArray does not support DestructElements any more, I am thinking of using smart pointer, especially, shared_ptr, as follows:

```
CArray<std::shared_ptr<CMyObject>, std::shared_ptr<CMyObject>>
```

I read the source codes of CArray and know it will allocate the element space in heap. However, in document at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/smart-pointers-modern-cpp?view=vs-2015 , it said "Do not use the new or malloc expression on the smart pointer itself.", which means the smart pointer should not be allocated in heap. So whether can I use smart pointer as an element in CArray?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not familiar with `CArray`, but allocate a smartpointer on heap is nothing wrong.

Comment: just a example, there is nothing wrong with a `class` contains a smart pointer and is allocated with `new`.

Comment: The article is about using smart pointers as local variables, the advice ensures that RAII works.  That doesn't apply to your code since you store them in an array.  It is the CArray destructor that needs to destroy the pointers.  It does.  Don't use the 2nd template argument, not necessary.

Comment: As far as I'm concerned ,we could use smart pointer as an element in CArray. We can use "new" on the shared_ptr to allocate the element space. I suggest you could refer to the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42663978/correct-way-to-allocate-memory-to-stdshared-ptr)